# pyspark: dataframes write to parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following error when running through pyspark script to load a parquet table.I don't have a issue  when testing through pyspark shell

Interactive mode works fine:

```
 df_writer = pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter(df)
 df_writer.saveAsTable('test', format='parquet', mode='overwrite',path='xyz/test_table.parquet')
```

Script mode throws an error :

```
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1//bin/spark-submit --jars /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/-2.0.1/jars/commons-csv-1.2.jar /home/mapr/scripts/pyspark_load.py
17/02/17 14:57:06 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mapr/scripts/2_pyspark_load.py", line 23, in <module>
    df_writer = pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter(df)
NameError: name 'pyspark' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also save your dataframe in a much easier way:

```
df.write.parquet("xyz/test_table.parquet", mode='overwrite')
# 'df' is your PySpark dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between interactive and spark_submit for my scripts is that I have to import pyspark. So for example

```
import pyspark

df_writer = pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter(df)
# Rest of Code
```